# Enable source code repositories (16.04 LTS)

Tags: 16.04, repository

How do I enable source code repositories in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

---

*Note: THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE, AS THE OTHER QUESTION WAS FOR A DIFFERENT VERSION OF UBUNTU.*

Comment: Software & Updates > click on Source code so box turns a color, close > reload sources

Comment: Thank you. If you would like, you may want to post it as an answer so I can give you full credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Software & Updates > click on Source code so box turns a color, close > reload sources. You may or may not get a checkmark vs -, doesn't matter as long as it's colored

If you have any ppa's enabled that you also want sources from then go to the  Other Software tab & enable the (Source code) entry per ppa